# Android UI (Activity) hangs while BroadcastReceiver is trying to make httpConnection

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, httpurlconnection, freeze

My android application has a `BroadcastReceiver`. At start I start a `Service` that has an `AlarmManager` for calling my receiver periodically every 10 minutes and the receiver tries to make a http connection. When the receiver is trying to make a httpConnection sometimes it takes times in lines `httpConnection.getResponseCode();` or in `androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);` and in these situations android UI (Activity) hangs and waits until the receiver's operation is completed. But I think the BroadcastReceiver's operation is in a separate thread and it should not pauses UI thread.

Why this happens and how can I correct it?

My httpconnection in receiver:

```
private Object callWebServiceMethodPublic(String url,
            String namespace, String methodName,
            HashMap<String, Object> parameters, String soapAction)
            throws Exception {

        //System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

        Log.i("WebService", "URL: " + url);
        Log.i("WebService", "MethodName: " + methodName);

        Log.i("SendMapMovements", "1.2.3.1");

        URL myurl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = myurl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20 * 1000);
        //connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

        Log.i("SendMapMovements", "1.2.3.2");

        int responseCode = -1;
        try {
            responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            Log.i("SendMapMovements", "1.2.3.3");

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            if (e1.toString().contains("Network is unreachable")) {

            } else if (e1.toString().contains("SocketTimeoutException")) {

            } else {
                throw e1;
            }
        }
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            httpConnection.disconnect();

            Log.i("SendMapMovements", "1.2.3.4");

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);

            if (parameters != null) {
                String[] keys = new String[0];
                keys = (String[]) parameters.keySet().toArray(keys);
                Object[] vals = (Object[]) parameters.values().toArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
                    request.addProperty(keys[i], vals[i]);
                    Log.i("WebService", keys[i] + ": " + vals[i]);
                }
            }

            Log.i("SendMapMovements", "1.2.3.5");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url,
                    TimeOutInSeconds * 1000);

            Log.i("SendMapMovements", "1.2.3.6");

            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);

                Log.i("SendMapMovements", "1.2.3.7");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e.toString().contains("XmlPullParserException")) {
                    throw new Exception(...);
                }
            }

            Object so = envelope.getResponse();
            System.gc();

            return so;

        } else {
            httpConnection.disconnect();
            Log.i("SendMapMovements", "1.2.3.8");
            String strErrorDescription = getHttpErrorDescription(responseCode);
            throw new Exception(strErrorDescription);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *But I think the BroadcastReceiver's operation is in a separate thread and it should not pauses UI thread.* - Your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @Luksprog should I define an AsyncTask in my receiver?

Comment: If the receiver is set in the manifest then you shouldn't start a new thread or `AsyncTask` as Android could kill the process after `onReceive` finishes. In this case you should use a `Service`(or better an `IntentService`).

Comment: @Luksprog can you explain more? As I mentioned, my receiver is called by a Service.

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup. At start(the system's start or your app's?) you start the service and from there you call directly the receiver at each 10 minutes? Or you just start the service when your app runs and in that time you call the receiver(in this case wouldn't be simpler to just call the web service directly from the service)?

Comment: @Luksprog at the start of my application for the first time I start my service and then always this service is running. this service uses a receiver for calling webservice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must run your connection code whithin new `Thread`, not on `UI Thread (Main Thread)`, because the `BroadcastReceiver` and your `Activity` runs on the same thread.

Comment: should I define an AsyncTask in my receiver?

Comment: As I saw your code, there is no need to do it in AsyncTask, do it just in a new thread.